# Flutter deep link turn on

Tags: android, ios, flutter, deep-linking

i'am adding deep link in my app

why default value supported web links is off?
[image]

that is my manifest

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

   <data android:scheme="http" />
   <data android:scheme="https" />

   <data android:host="exempl.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

I test mobile part with adb. This is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified the wrong sha256

i use jks
but write google play sha256

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to deep link http/s urls from `exampl.com` (unless you put that value in your paste to avoid showing the actual domain).

For https links you need to make sure to provide, in your domain, an `assetlinks.json` file that will associate your app with the web domain you are trying to link. Until you do that, Android can't associate your app with the domain by default.

Perhaps these tutorials will help you through this process:

- https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#publish-json
- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-app-links-deploy-assetlinks-json-in-minutes-d7082dffcac

Comment: Hello, the files have been added to the server. That's why I'm asking the question here.

Maybe there is another problem